# Android RecyclerView inside Fragment is not updating Loader content

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-loadermanager, android-loader, android-recyclerview

I have Fragment and it uses `RecyclerView Adapter` with `LoaderManager` to list items. `RecyclerView` i use is from this [address.](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59) I've implemented `LoaderManager` in Fragment and gave context of its Activity to `RecyclerView`.

When i add new item to list, it does not refresh and show new item in list. I use same `Adapter` and structure on another activity and it works good. But here i use `RecyclerView` with `Loader` inside Fragment and it does not refresh list when i add item, instead i have to go back(finish fragment) and enter again.

I have 2 tables like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28946355/database-choice-for-creating-two-connected-tables). First I get `cursor` from `student_course` table and from that `cursor` i get student ids of specific class. Then using data of first `cursor`, i get second `cursor` from `students` table which has list of students from same class. Then i send second `cursor` to `adapter`. I do below operation on both `onCreateView()` and `onCreateLoader`:

```
String[] projection0 = {
            DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_STUDENT_ID,
            DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_COURSE_ID};
    String selection0=DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_COURSE_ID + "=?";
    String selectionArgs0[]={String.valueOf(courseId)};
    mDataset0=getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI2, projection0,selection0,selectionArgs0,null);


    if(mDataset0.getCount()!=0) {
        //BATCH
        List<String> selectionList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mDataset0.moveToFirst();

        ...
        String[] projection1 = {
                DatabaseOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID,
                DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_STUDENT_NUMBER,
                DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_STUDENT_NAME,
                DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_STUDENT_CARD_ID,
                DatabaseOpenHelper.COL_STUDENT_COLOR};
        selection1 = selection1.substring(0, selection1.length() - 2) + ")";
        mDataset1 = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI1, projection1, selection1, selectionArgs1, null);

    }else{
        mDataset1=null;
    }
...
mAdapter = new studentListAdapter(getActivity(),mDataset1,this);
```

mDataset1 is students of same class.

1) What might be the problem ? 2) Is there any way to implement LoaderManager class inside

**Update 1:** When i change `selection1` and `selectionArgs1` to `null`, it updates list immediately after i add item. But it shows all students from every class because i didn't specify selection.

**Update 2:** When i check `onLoadFinished()` i see that new cursor, after loading new content, is still same as old.

Comment: show some code so we can identify the problem

Comment: @hrskrs some clarifications added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** I realized that cursor is not changing when new data is added, so when i add new data i call  `getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID,null,this)` (by `localBrodCastManager` in my case) which reloads cursor (calls `onCreateLoader()`) and new data is shown on list. (as Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11092861/3736955)). This does trick.

**2)** I found that the reason `cursor` does not change when item is added, because on `onCreateLoader()` i returned `cursor` with specific `id` selection of students, which means `cursor` will not change until there is change on that items with specific `ids` i have given. So, if there is new item added, my `cursor`is not changed, but if one of the items(which is listed) is removed or changed, then cursor is changed. Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29181780/3736955).